# Finding the percentage of rows mysql query

Tags: mysql

Following is the mysql table 'transaction' which contains transaction id and its created timestamp

```
+-------------+-----------------+
|  id    | created_at           |
+-------------+-----------------+
| 101    |  2015-04-13 11:42:41 |
| 102    |  2015-04-14 10:42:41 |
| 103    |  2015-04-16 11:42:41 |
| 104    |  2015-04-16 11:42:41 |
| 105    |  2015-04-17 11:42:41 |
+-------------+-----------------+
```

Need to write a MySQL query to -
Find the percentage of transaction(s) of total transaction created between two dates/timestamp, for example
2015-04-14 to 2015-04-16

Comment: Go on. Try something. And see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Or just wait for Gordon, GMB, or Akina to pop along

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it with simple query:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(IF(created_at BETWEEN '2015-04-14' AND '2015-04-16 23:59:59', 1, null) \
    COUNT(*) AS percentage
FROM table;
```